# Repeating background gradient with html and body at 100%

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the background gradient to stretch the entire height of the page and not break once the viewport ends, as it does here http://jsfiddle.net/szfiddle/hTU7d/

However, I also need to keep the height at 100% for the html and body tags in order for the pages where the main window is not the size of the viewport to go all the way to the bottom, like here:  http://jsfiddle.net/szfiddle/hTU7d/2/, so taking out one of those tags from the height 100% part isn't an option unless there is another way to do it.

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="mainWindow">
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
<p>Content here</p>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body,html {
    height: 100%;
}

body{
  background: #70bg32;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #183023 0%, #24543a 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#183023), color-stop(100%,#24543a)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #183023 0%,#24543a 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #183023 0%,#24543a 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #183023 0%,#24543a 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #183023 0%,#24543a 100%); /* W3C */
}
#mainWindow {
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #fffff6;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hTU7d/3/)

Simply add `background-attachment:fixed;` to your body CSS

[**More from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment)

> the background-attachment CSS property determines whether that image's
>   position is fixed within the viewport, or scrolls along with its
>   containing block.

Comment: I know I tried that, didn't realize it had to be AFTER the background tags.  Thanks!

Comment: Its only because you'd otherwise override it with your generic setting of the `background` property- glad to help :)